# How can I compare map-like elements with XMLUnit

Tags: xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have below xml data:

Control:

```
 <Data>

        <propertyValues>
            <propertyName>Name1</propertyName>
            <value>
                <text>
                    <value>Value1</value>
                </text>
            </value>
        </propertyValues>
        <propertyValues>
            <propertyName>Name2</propertyName>
            <value>
                <text>
                    <value>Value2</value>
                </text>
            </value>
        </propertyValues>
 </Data>
```

Test:

```
 <Data>
            <propertyValues>
                <propertyName>Name2</propertyName>
                <value>
                    <text>
                        <value>Value2</value>
                    </text>
                </value>
            </propertyValues>
            <propertyValues>
                <propertyName>Name1</propertyName>
                <value>
                    <text>
                        <value>Value1</value>
                    </text>
                </value>
            </propertyValues>
 </Data>
```

And I would expect these 2 documents are "same".

How can I config xmlUnit to make it work? (I'm using xmlunit 2.6.3)

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty similar to the running example of the "Selecting Nodes" part of XMLUnit's User Guide.

You need to use an `ElementSelector` that picks the correct `propertyValues` element when looking at the list of elements and then decides to compare the elements that contain the same nested text inside the only child element named `propertyName`. This directly translates into

```java
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("propertyValues")
    .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./propertyName", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
   ...
```

and then you need to add whatever other rules are required to make the rest work. Looking at the visible rest of your example there are no ambiguous children and a simple

```java
   ...
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

will do.

Comment: btw,  your sample just pickup the 'propertyName' child node, how about the value node?

Comment: should it be: .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./propertyName|./value/text/value", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)) ?

Comment: It picks only `propertyName` because I assumed this is what identifies the `propertyValues` that need to be compared. If you need `vaues` as well to make XMLUnit pick the correct pairs then you need to adjust. This is really **only** about what it takes to make XMLUnit pick the right `propertyValues` - for all other `byName` is used and seems to be sufficient.

Comment: I just found that I can use ElementSelectors.and() to combine selector for propertyName and selector for value, thanks  a lot!